# Partitioning real numbers with sum $1$ to sets

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, real-numbers

If the sum of a finite number of positive real numbers is $1$ and each of them is less than $x$, then those real numbers can be partitioned into $50$ sets (some of which may be empty) such that the sum of the elements in a set is at most $x.$ Find the least possible value of $x.$

It is easy to verify that $\frac{1}{50} \le x$, so I think that the least possible value might be $\frac{1}{50}$, but I haven't proved that.

Comment: "the real numbers can be partitioned into 50 sets..." this must be the set of real number whose sum is $1$ that can be partitioned...

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry, made it clear.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. All the numbers are less than a real number $x$.

Comment: Are the numbers required to be positive?

Comment: @Math1000 Yes..

Comment: Hint: the statement is not true for $x=1/50$.  Suppose you have $51$ real numbers, all equal to $1/51$.  You can try to fit them into $50$ bins, each with capacity at most $1/50$; but some bin will have sum at least $2/51$.  Thus, for the statement to be true, you need $x\ge 2/51$.

Comment: @Tad Thanks! So if I show that the statement is true for $\frac{2}{51}$ I am done, isn't it?

Comment: Right -- *if* it's true for $x=2/51$ then that's the smallest $x$.